# Compare the elements of 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two 2d numpy arrays, a and b. I want to compare if every element in b array is in array a. For example, if [2,1] is in [1,4,3,2] the exit will be True, if [2,1] is in [3,1] the exit will be False etc... Same procedure with [1,3] element.
The exit has to be [True, False, False] for [2,1] element and [True, True, False] for [1,3] element.

```
a = np.array([[1,4,3,2],[3,1],[1,7,8,9,4]])
b = np.array([[2,1],[1,3]])

[True,False,False]
[True,True,False]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be -

```
In [80]: np.vstack([np.isin(b,i).all(1) for i in a])
Out[80]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the numpy.in1d function.. it checks if elements from the first array are contained in the second array:

```
In [18]: [[np.in1d(bx, ax).all() for ax in a] for bx in b]
Out[18]: [[True, False, False], [True, True, False]]
```